# PowerShell with Tabs Window Management

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a way to run one powershell window and have multiple tabs in this window that you can jump between without have several powershell windows open?

Answer (score 17):

If you are using a GUI, PowerShell ISE (Integrated Scripting Environment) will do this. ISE will allow you to have multiple scripts open and once and run them independently.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of a way to save/open a "workspace", similar to NotePad++? I have a handful of different scripts that I always use together.

Comment: @MikeCole No, I don't know of a method, although it looks like it's possible to make your own plugin to do so. I am sure one exists out there somewhere

Answer (score 10):

PowerShell runs very nicely in [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).

[image: ConEmu screenshot]

Comment: You might like to use [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) with that too, to make the experience even nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the **`Windows Terminal`**:
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

[image: Screenshot]